# Assigning memory size dynamically causes stack smashing error

Tags: c, file, strcat

The situation is rather simple, but I have no clue why I am overflowing the buffer. I am trying to print out the contents of a file. Assigning a `static int` to the `count` works, but any method of finding out the file's size causes this error to appear and the program to exit.

**Source:**

```
char path[] = "upload/";
strcat(path, filename);

FILE *file;

file = fopen(path, "r");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int count = ftell(file);
printf("%d\n",count);
char *buffer = malloc(count);

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);


fread(buffer, count, 1, file);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
free(buffer);
fclose(file);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `ftell` returns a long int

Comment: You cannot *`strcat`* to an array like that.

Comment: You forgot to allocate one extra byte for the terminating NUL character

Comment: Additionally you're not checking the return values of *any* of these functions. You **must** check and act upon the return value of `fopen`, `malloc`, `fseek`, `fread` etc. If you don't, you'll *never* have any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
char path[] = "upload/";
strcat(path, filename);
```

The array `path` has only space allocated (i.e., sized for) for the `upload/` and null terminator. Using this as the destination for `strcat()` is accessing memory out of bounds, which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) (*emphasis mine*)

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`'\0'`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and **the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable;**

That said,

- [`ftell()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell) returns a `long`, you should change the type of `count` accordingly.
- you should always check for the returned value of function calls for success, before making use of the returned value.